# Stripe Connect with node.js and oauth

Tags: oauth-2.0, stripe-payments

I am trying to send the proper request to Stripe to process my connect tokens, and I can't get it right.

This is the curl request they give as an example:

```
curl -X POST https://connect.stripe.com/oauth/token \
  -d client_secret=sk_test_******************** \
  -d code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE \
  -d grant_type=authorization_code
```

This is my attempt with node-oath:

```
var OAuth2 = OAuth.OAuth2;    
  var client_id = 'ca_******************';
  var secret = 'sk_test_*****************';
  var oauth2 = new OAuth2(client_id,
    secret, 
    'https://connect.stripe.com/', 
    null,
    'oauth/token', 
    null);
  oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken(
    {'code':'ac_******************'},
    {'grant_type':'authorization_code'},
    function (e, access_token, refresh_token, results){
    console.log('bearer: ',e);
  });
```

I am able to get a response but it is always:

```
{ statusCode: 400,
  data: '{\n  "error": "invalid_grant",\n  "error_description": "Authorization code does not exist: "\n}' }
```

I know my keys are right, I just think I am putting them in the wrong places. There is almost no documentation on the node-oauth module so I'm not sure what the arguments are supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

The auth code passed from stripe to your callback URL is case sensitive, check that your server is not forcing to lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem...

The problem was solved by removing the parameter definition "{'code':'ac_******************'}" and just passing in the code "'ac_******************'"...

```
oauth2.getOAuthAccessToken(
    'ac_******************',
    {'grant_type':'authorization_code'},
    function (e, access_token, refresh_token, results){
    console.log('bearer: ',e);
  });
```